# How to handle validations(RegEx) while localizing application

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, mvvm, localization

We decided to support other languages by our project and I started localizing it.

In some text boxes, we are using **text validations** where we allow only certain characters like only alphabets from a to z or only certain characters. When we run our application in other language OS like Hebrew or Hindi, user will not be able to enter any text in those text boxes due to validation.

How can we make these rules **localize\Globalize**? How to handle these types of scenarios while localizing application

Comment: I propose doing an attribute which implementation is localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{L}` along with your Regex for achieving the required validation for all languages.

To match any letter character from any language use:

```
\p{L}
```

If you also want to match numbers:

```
[\p{L}\p{Nd}]+

`\p{L}` ... matches a character of the unicode category letter.
            it is the short form for [\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}]
              \p{Ll} ... matches lowercase letters. (abc)
              \p{Lu} ... matches uppercase letters. (ABC)
              \p{Lt} ... matches titlecase letters. 
              \p{Lm} ... matches modifier letters.
              \p{Lo} ... matches letters without case. (中文)
```

`\p{Nd}` ... matches a character of the unicode category decimal digit.

Just replace: `^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$` with `^[\p{L}0-9\s]+$`